# What is the rationale behind using signed values for representing time?

Tags: time, language-agnostic, signed

In many languages, a signed value is used to represent time instead of an unsigned one. What is the rationale behind this? I'm interested in this in a general way, not just a specific language.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic], and read [ask]. This is too opionion-based ("why do you think") or too broad (Python / C# / C++ / C; "chosen to represent time"... where? how?), or both.

Comment: The negative sign is a way to differentiate between "before" and "after".

Answer (score 2):

Time extends indefinitely in both directions. (At least for practical purposes, the Big Bang notwithstanding.) You may only wish to measure times after the start of some process, but some software works with times in the past, such as historical records, physics calculations, archeological studies, records of birth dates of patients, and so on.